# Python Search Engine with Selenium & BeautifulSoup - Delays displaying Search Results

Tags: python, django, selenium, web-scraping, search-engine

Here's the basic set-up: Python 2 on Django, Selenium & BeautifulSoup, MqSQL (working on replacing Chrome with PhantomJS to reduce memory usage)

I built a search engine. Upon a user entering search criteria, I fill in forms based on the query, scrape the data from said sources, using my algorithm to sort and organize the data, and displays the results to the user.

However, from the moment the user hits the search button to actually seeing search results takes a between 30 seconds and 2 minutes. In today's "instant gratification" world, this is unacceptable. So, I need to reduce this time wait time as much as possible.

What are the ways I can speed this up?

Comment: Yes, of course it can be done, but it may well involve a rearchitecture of your solution. Even without that, we'd need proper metrics/logs to know where the time was being spent. Not to mention something about your usage patterns: you can't satisfy every single user by magic. And your algorithm could be incredibly complex or powerful.

Comment: @AndrewRegan I know I can't satisfy every user, but the "lengthy" wait time is a common complaint. I'm willing to do whatever it takes to make it better, even it means I need to scale up hardware. Which metrics, logs, and usage patterns would you need specifically? 

Basically, once users hit the search button, they're taken to a loading page. After about 30s-2min, they're taken to the search results page where I lazy load chunks of the search results.

Comment: Realistically I don't think SO is the format for this, as it's for specific problems not s/w consultancy. However, I'll say that you'll never get ~ 3 second turnarounds with Selenium anywhere in the stack. Going further, you want that data before the user has even hit Search: your algo needs those 3 seconds, you can't waste them parsing web pages. As I said, that may radically change your solution.

Comment: @AndrewRegan I think this issue is definitely valid for SO bc there are programmers, besides myself, who have issues related to the topic of searching/scraping dynamic data with speed (_efficiency_). The issue is that in order to scrape the information we nee to display, we need to interact with forms and js. If not selenium, what's better? The other issue is that the information we pull isn't static (users can purchase these products and these products can be sold out) so we can't really cache for long - if that's what you're saying? I'm fine with reworking this if I did it wrong.